# Kafka does not correctly assign partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running a kafka cluster on 3 identical VMs with 4 cores and 16GB of RAM.
The topic configuration includes 6 different partitions for each of them.
Kafka version: kafka_2.13-2.8.0
Zookeeper version: 3.5.7

```
broker.id=0
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/data2
num.partitions=6
default.replication.factor=2
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=2
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=48
log.segment.bytes=268435456
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=kafka-1:2181,kafka-2:2181,kafka-3:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
message.max.bytes=2000000
listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9092
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=20000
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
```

All servers are in the same tenant and also in the same subnet.
After the cluster restart the partitions are mainly assigned to only two of the servers, while the third one is has only a few of the remaining partitions

[image]

Is there any way I can re-balance the partitions without restarting the cluster? As a side note, a cluster restart does not guarantee the correct distribution of the partitions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you ended up with such an unbalanced cluster. Unless you started with only 2 brokers and added the 3rd one later, partitions should have ended better distributed across the 3 brokers.

Anyway, Kafka does not redistribute partitions when it restarts, since it would need to move all the partition data across brokers. You need to manually instruct Kafka to move them.

The open-source tool included with Kafka is called `kafka-reassign-partitions`. It is the same procedure that you would need to follow if you added a new broker: https://kafka.apache.org/32/documentation.html#basic_ops_cluster_expansion

1. Generate a reassignment plan with the `--generate` option. Review and edit if required the generated json file.
2. Execute the plan with the `--execute` option.
3. Check progress with `--verify` flag.